# VGEXTEND: How to avoid wiping a swap signature in /dev/sda3?

Tags: linux, lvm, swap

The problem:

```
[root@195623 ~]# vgs
  VG            #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  fedora_195623   1   3   0 wz--n- 9,50g    0 
[root@195623 ~]# vgextend fedora_195623 /dev/sda3
WARNING: swap signature detected on /dev/sda3 at offset 4086. Wipe it? [y/n]
```

The only command I could find to help was `swapoff`, but the only result is "`BAD ARGUMENT`" (even though when I looked at examples of `swapoff`'s use, it is to be used on the `/dev/sd*` devices).

Comment: Did you run `pvcreate /dev/sda3` before running `vgextend`? Does `/dev/sda3` appear in the list of PVs as shown by `pvs` or `pvdisplay`?

Comment: The `/dev/sda3` wasn't present amongst the PVs, so I ran `pvcreate /dev/sda3` earlier, but it also lead to the "wipe the swap signature" situation.

Comment: (Just to be sure: Is it the wiping-of-the-swap-signature which causes Linux to have problems during the next boot? Because I specifically want for Linux to work after I do the VG extending on `/dev/sda3`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to use `/dev/sda3` as a new LVM PV.
- `/dev/sda3` was previously used as a swap device.

You have 2 choices:

- Overwrite/wipe the previous contents of the device and make it an LVM PV.
- Don't overwrite, leave it alone, and abort the operation. Naturally, it will not become an LVM PV.

You cannot have it both ways. If you want to use this device as an LVM PV then answer "yes". If you realized that you made a mistake and this device is indeed supposed to be a swap device then answer "no".

Comment: Thanks. :)

So far I assumed that wiping-the-swap-signature was the thing which caused  my linux-booting problems, (because my linux-boot failed after each wipe) and that is why I tried to avoid the wipe.I just now saw that it was apparently something *else* (namely, extending a VG before creating a PV) which caused my problems with the boot. And the problem is gone now.

Answer (score 2):

A swap signature does not necessarily mean that the system is currently actively using this partition for swap. It just means it looks like a swap partition on disk. And that's what LVM is asking you: do you want to wipe this thing that already seems to be on the disk or not?

If `swapoff` says the device is not in use, then you're good. If in doubt, have a look at `/proc/swaps`. To make extra sure, you should also see if there are any `swap` entries for `/dev/sda3` in your `/etc/fstab` and remove them.