# What do I need to do to finish this service/timer?

Tags: cron, systemd, gentoo, services

I'm trying to write a `.service` file to update my `linux_logo` uptime. I had this working as a cronjob in SysV init, but lost my example when I lost my system after [upgrading to LVM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294119/is-this-worth-converting-to-lvm-and-separate-home-mount).  I have the following file as `/etc/conf.d/linux-logo`:

```
# Seq   Description             Output
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# ##                            #
# #B    Bogomips                374.37
# #C    Compiled Date           #47 Fri Jan 8 10:37:09 EST 1999
# #E    User Text               My Favorite Linux Distribution
#       Displayed with -t
# #H    Hostname                deranged
# #L    Load average            Load average 0.04, 0.01, 0.01
# #M    Megahertz               188Mhz
#       where supported
# #N    Number of CPU's         Two
# #O    OS Name                 Linux
# #P    Processor or Processors Processor
# #R    Ram                     64M
#       in Megabytes
# #S    Plural                  s
# #T    Type of CPU             K6
# #U    Uptime                  Uptime 10 hours 59 minutes
# #V    Version of OS           2.2.0-pre5
# #X    CPU Vendor              AMD
# \\n   carriage return

LOGO="-L gentoo-alt"
FORMAT="Gentoo #O `cat /etc/gentoo-release | awk '{ print $5,$6 }'`\n#O #V, Compiled #C\n#N #X #T #M CPU#S, #R RAM, #B Bogomips\n#U\n#H / \l  \n"
FORMATNET="Gentoo #O `cat /etc/gentoo-release | awk '{ print $5,$6 }'`\n#O #V, Compiled #C\n#N #X #T #M CPU#S, #R RAM, #B Bogomips\n#U\n#H\n"
OPTIONS="-f -u"
```

I've written the following service file:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/linux-logo.service
[Unit]
Description=Updates LinuxLogo every 15 Minutes

[Service]
```

and this timer file:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/linux-logo.timer
[Unit]
Description=Run linux-logo.service every 15 minutes

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/15
```

As you can see, I don't know where I'm supposed to go to finish off the `[Service]` entry. I'm lost on how to pass all the variables, `LOGO`, `FORMAT`, `FORMATNET`, and `OPTIONS`.  Help would be appreciated.

---

On a side note, I'd like to add this to my terminal inside my Desktop Environment also, but I've got to get the update working first, i.e. each time I open a terminal application the logo should print itself and the updated uptime.

Comment: where does your logo appear?

Comment: Right now, it only appears on my TTY's, but since I use graphical.target, I hardly ever see it

Comment: Issued to use startx, and I'd log out of X and see it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `linuxlogo` manages to appear on the tty consoles, but you can run it from your Unit file by adding to the `[Service]` section

```
Type=oneshot
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/linux-logo
ExecStart=/usr/bin/linuxlogo
```

Remember to `sudo systemctl enable linux-logo.timer` for the next boot, and start it by hand similarly with `sudo systemctl start linux-logo.timer`. Also, after any changes to the 2 files do `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`.

Comment: It writes to /etc/issue, but how can I get /etc/issue to appear in gnome-terminal?

Comment: I'm afraid I know hardly anything about gnome. You might simply add a `cat /etc/issue` command to your interactive shell startup file, eg `~/.bashrc` for bash.